# (CSS) show text on each message

Tags: css

I'm trying to customize a chat on cytu.be. My objective is to make it look like Twitch's chat. I've made a lot of progress so far, but I just stumbled against my first wall and I'm pretty much stuck since I'm pretty new to CSS.

This is the problem: cytu.be shows the name of the message sender only in the first message, but I want to make it so it shows it on every message, like on Twitch:

[image: Problem]

As you can see, when you send 2 messages in a row, it shows the name only in the first one.
I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: Objective]

I changed the color of my name in the past using this code:

```css
.chat-msg-mopolo .username { color: rgb(0, 255, 127) !important; }
.chat-msg-mopolo2 .username { color: rgb(0, 100, 255) !important; }
```

```html
<html>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo">
    <span class="userlist_owner">
    <strong class="username">mopolo: </strong></span>
    <span>This is my first message</span>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo">
<span>And this is my second message</span></div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo2">
    <span class="userlist_owner">
    <strong class="username">mopolo2: </strong></span>
    <span>This is my first message as second user</span>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo2">
<span>And this is my second message as second user</span></div>
</html>
```

So I tried doing this:

```css
.chat-msg-mopolo .username { color: rgb(0, 255, 127) !important; }
.chat-msg-mopolo2 .username { color: rgb(0, 100, 255) !important; }
.linewrap [class*="chat-msg-"]::before {
    content: .username;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo">
    <span class="userlist_owner">
    <strong class="username">mopolo: </strong></span>
    <span>This is my first message</span>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo">
<span>And this is my second message</span></div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo2">
    <span class="userlist_owner">
    <strong class="username">mopolo2: </strong></span>
    <span>This is my first message as second user</span>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg-mopolo2">
<span>And this is my second message as second user</span></div>
</html>
```

But it didn't work. I'm scared that even if fixed, it won't detect the sender of the message and it's going to place a random username instead of the actual sender.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: To stand a chance of being able to answer your question, we'd need to see a sample of the representative HTML that's rendered to your browser.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and you're totally right. I added the html code to the snippet, hopefully it's easier to understand now. I'm still scratching my brain trying to figure this out. Cheers.